# display a save bottom edit text in editable button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, contenteditable

here is my code. i have a text. and a button for editing the text.i want to click the edit button then that time display a btn as name save . for saving the change that i have. what should i do? help me friends

```
 <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../../Editable/css/minified-std-acount.css">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="../../../eanjoman/js/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function(e) {

    $('button').click(function(){
    var $div=$('div'),
     isEditable=$div.is('.editable');
     $('div').prop('contenteditable',!isEditable).toggleClass('editable')
     })
     });
     </script>
     <style>
     .editable{ background:#EAEAEA}
     </style>

      </head>

    <body>
    <div>Some text</div><br><br><button>Toggle editable</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can just add one line code here:

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/0dw9apfy/)**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var $div=$('div'),
     isEditable=$div.is('.editable');
     $('div').prop('contenteditable',!isEditable).toggleClass('editable')
     $(this).text('Save'); //Add this
})
```

---

**UPDATE**

**[UPDATED DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/0dw9apfy/1/)**

To toggle it back just check for its `text` as below:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    var $div=$('div'),
     isEditable=$div.is('.editable');
    $('div').prop('contenteditable',!isEditable).toggleClass('editable')
    if($(this).text()!="Save") //Add this condition
        $(this).text('Save');
    else
        $(this).text('Toggle editable');
})
```

Comment: Anytime! Do Mark it as answer if it helped you!